# Finding the gradient of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that for the following function:

\begin{equation*}
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{Q}^3 \\
            \sin(x_1x_2x_3) & \quad \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

$\nabla f(0,0,0) = 0$ (which I have concluded by computing the partial derivatives at this point).

To accomplish this I've tried using the limit definition, but because of the function being piecwise, I don't know how to proceed from:

$$ \lim_{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\to 0} \frac{f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{|(x_1,x_2,x_3)|} $$

(EDIT: I considered bounding it above by the absolute value of the sine option, but then I don't know how to show that the limit is $0$).

How does one proceed in such a case?

Comment: Your function is not derivable because it is defined on irrationals and rationals alltogether not even on a continuous way.

Comment: @BrunoLobo It's supposed to be differentiable at $0$.